# Downloading file with carrierwave from Rackspace cloudfiles not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I am using Carrierwave to upload text files to Rackspace, and have this working.  My setup is really standard:

Uploader:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "/my/local/path"
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class UploadedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

Carrierwave init file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider           => "Rackspace",
    :rackspace_username => "xxxxx",
    :rackspace_api_key  => "yyyyy"
  }
  config.fog_directory = "my_container"
  config.fog_host = "http://c000000.cdn.rackspacecloud.com"
  config.fog_public = false
end
```

I'm not uploading a file from a form, rather I am generating the file in a background process using delayed job, and then uploading it to Rackspace:

```
file = File.new("/my/local/path/some_text_file.txt", "r")
uploaded_file = UploadedFile.new
uploaded_file.file = file
uploaded_file.save
```

Up to this point, everything is fine.  I can see my files in my Rackspace account.
I also see that my model saved and I have the record in my uploaded_files table.

My issue is retrieving the file.  I've attempted the following:

```
downloader = FileUploader.new
downloader.retrieve_from_store!("some_text_file.txt")
```

I realize that retrieve_from_store! does not actually download the file.  However, what should come next is:

```
downloader.cache_stored_file!
```

But that line breaks because nothing was retrieved from the prior call.

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong on my download, as the following produces odd output:

```
f = UploadedFile.first
f.file.url

"/my/local/path/some_text_file.txt"
```

Based on all of the examples I've seen, I would expect f.file.url to return a Rackspace CDN url.  But its not, it returns the store_dir path instead.

**EDIT**

I should note that the underlying table for the UploadedFile model has a column named "file", which contains only the base name of the file, not a url or full path to Rackspace cloud files, which may be part of the issue...

Comment: It's intended that column contains only file name. The rest of the URL is built by carrierwave

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configured your RackSpace account to enable public access to your files. Under **Cloud / FilesContainers**, edit the settings to enable CDN. After that, the public link will be available through the CarrierWave::Uploader.url